# Arch Linux non-critical error on insertion of install disk

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux

I'm trying to install Arch Linux i686 on a 2008 laptop. Upon starting up the machine and booting from the live disk, I get the following three errors:

```
b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw" request failed (err=-12)
b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode15.fw" request failed (err=-12)
b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to 
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware 
and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully 
read all instructions on this website.
```

I take it that this means I don't have a proper driver, in this case, for a Broadcom wireless internet device of one kind or another. However, following the steps at that link doesn't help. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

What these messages are telling you is that you have a Broadcom wifi card which requires appropriate firmware to function properly. So, you **do** have a driver (and you should be thankful that your old pc has a wifi card which can be driven by *b43*, the FOSS alternative to the proprietary drivers which are really buggy), but you will also need to install extra software to have it work properly.

So you may proceed with the installation using your ethernet connection. After that is completed, you will find [in the Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/broadcom_wireless#Loading_the_b43.2Fb43legacy_kernel_module) all the information necessary to complete your task. At any rate, what you need to do is to download the firmware package [from this Web page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware/) into an empty directory  by choosing *Download the Tarball*, go to the directory and issue the commands:

```
 tar xvf b43-firmware.tar.gz
 cd b43-firmware
 makepkg -i
```

At this point you may need to restart your pc. When it comes up, your wifi card should work.